Dynamically creating columns in Azure Data Factory
I already issued my problem in this request and got it solved. Unfortunately my problem changed slightly and I needed support again :)
I have a table with 4 columns. ID, stock, warehouse, stockbin.
My table has multiple rows with the same ID, but different values for stock, warehouse and stockbin.
I want to transform the data so that only one row with the distinct ID remains.
For every value in stock, warehouse and stockbin I just want to have a new column with a rising counter.
Example:
id, warehouse, stock, stockbin
1, Berlin, 30, A5
1, Berlin, 20, A9
1, New York, 10, A16
2, Belgium, 5, A40
2, Spain, 10, A50

After transformation:
id, warehouse1, stock1, stockbin1, warehouse2, stock2, stockbin2, warehouse3, stock3, stockbin3
1, Berlin, 30, A5, Berlin, 20, A9, New York, 10, A16
2, Belgium, 5, A40, Spain, 10, A50

What would be a good way to solve? In my original request it only worked for 2 columns.
I changed it to three but then my stockbin is not stockbin1, stockbin2 and so on but stockbinA16, stockbinA50.
Any ideas?

To get the output as your required format you can follow below procedure in data flow:
Here is the sample data:

Setup the data source in dataflow and add windows function transformation to create  ws  column. Configure the transformation as follows:

Over:id
Sort:  id
Window columns:

toString(rowNumber())




Add pivot transformation to the windows transformation and configure the transformation as follows:

Group by:  id
Pivot key:  ws
Pivoted columns :

warehouse: max({ warehouse})
stock: max(stock)
stockbin: max(stockbin)




The new columns will create according to the data as mentioned below:

